# Heroku :: Persistant Application Error with no logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So inside my application, I get an Application Error when trying to connect to PayPal (sometimes).  However, I cannot retrieve the log of this error.  I've set `heroku config:add LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG` but I still can't see the error.

The way I do it is `heroku logs --tail` to see the streaming log text, and this usually works.

The very last thing I see when the error happens in my console is

```
2012-08-02T21:45:08+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 128.189.198.66 - - [02/Aug/2012:21:45:08 +0000]
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 1084 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) 
AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.57 Safari/537.1" weeve.it
```

Which looks perfectly normal.

Another weird thing is that once I encounter this problem in my browser, I will see an Application Error anytime after when visiting any page of the application, even pages that I *know* do not have errors.  Once I clear my cookies, the application loads normally again.

Any troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could it be that the paypal logic is overwriting a cookie that your app sets?

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of your cookies seem to be causing the problem, can you try writing the contents of the cookies to the log in a before_filter in your application controller

`Rails.logger.info(cookies.inspect)`

Let me know if that sheds any insight.